# How to localize an acoustic source underwater with a hydrophone array

Tags: localization, underwater

I am working on an Autonomous underwater vehicle (AUV), and I do not know how to localize an acoustic source underwater

I know that I will use an array of hydrophones but how can actually get the position of the acoustic source

-are there any available commercial chips for acoustic signal processing?
-are there any available books discussing that topic technically?
-is there any known strategy for underwater acoustic source localization?

Comment: this may or may not help https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/examples/acoustic-beamforming-using-a-microphone-array.html  ........... and this ..... https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/examples/direction-of-arrival-estimation-with-beamscan-mvdr-and-music.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to use the phase difference to calculate the direction -- rotate your array until all sensors get the same phase, and you've found the direction to the source (or do some calculations based on the phase difference -- this does not require any mechanical movement).

For the distance -- use two separate arrays and triangulate the position from the two angles. If you don't have two arrays -- use the left and right half of the same array to calculate angles and go from there, the precision might suffer a bit, though.

Comment: I got the main Idea for what you are saying. Do you have any books or articles discussing these calculations with details ?

Comment: @ShehabAldeen a quick google search for "hydrophone array" returned http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/732042.pdf